# How to copy only numbers from masked textbox to a label?

Tags: c#, winforms, maskedtextbox

I made a masked textbox for saving numbers with the mask **(999) 000-0000** and I want to show only numbers in label but when I do that, it also copies the parantheses and lines.
I know it copies all the text. How I can only copy numbers entered not with mask?
(windows form)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = maskedTextBox1.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to set `TextMaskFormat` to `ExcludePromptAndLiterals` just before reading it's value:

```
maskedTextBox1.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals;
Console.WriteLine(maskedTextBox1.Text); 
//will print 3123 when value in the mask textbox is (31) 23 for mask (00) 00
```

And after this set Format back:

```
maskedTextBox1.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.IncludeLiterals;
```

Even if you won't set format back to `IncludeLiterals`, UI control still would show masked text `(31) 23` and will work as usual. This is done if your other logic relies on masked `Text` field.

So if you don't have such dependencies, you can set this value right in the Visual Studio designer in properties window for `maskedTextBox1`

Comment: tnx, but why did you write Console.WriteLine() while it should be label1.Text = maskedTextBox1.Text;  ?

Comment: it doesn't matter. `maskedTextBox1.Text` returns a `string`, so if you would assign it to a label, your label would show a raw number. Try it yourself. I just wanted to show how I get that number and read it without forms or debugging